# Construct function with special decay

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, estimation

Let $r,R>0$ such that $R>2r$. I want to construct a twice differentiable function $f=f_{r,R}$ so that
\begin{align}
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
0, 0<|x|<r\\
1, 2r<|x|<R\\
0, |x|>2R
\end{cases}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
|f'(r)|\leq 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{r} \text{  if } r<|x|<2r\\
\frac{1}{R} \text{ if } |x|\geq 2r
\end{cases}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
|f''(r)|\leq 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{r^2} \text{  if } r<|x|<2r\\
\frac{1}{R^2} \text{ if } |x|\geq 2r.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
On $(2r,R)$ the derivatives obviously fulfil the estimates. Now, e.g. on $(R,2R)$ I thought I might glue some $\log$ function, so take for example $f(x)=1$ on $(R,R+\varepsilon)$ and $f(x)=\log\left((2R_2-x)\frac{e}{R_2}\right)$ on $(R+\varepsilon,2R)$ for $\varepsilon >0$ small. At least all conditions in $R_2$ are fulfilled. Now the function should be zero in $(2R-\varepsilon, 2R)$. Any suggestions how I can modify the $\log$ part? The part $(r,2r)$ should then be similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If such a function $f$ existed on the reals, that would mean $f(R) = 1$ and $f(2R) = 0$. Since $f$ is twice differentiable, the first derivative of $f$ is continuous. We also know by continuity of the first derivative that $f'(R) = 0$ because $f$ is constant on $(2r,R)$.

Consider the first order Taylor expansion $P_1(x)$ of $f$ around $x = R$: we see that $$P_1(x) = 1 + 0(x-R) \implies P_1(2R) = 1.$$

Taylor's theorem (Lagrange form) for the remainder (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem) applied on the interval $[R,2R]$ says that for $c = \sup_{x \in [R,2R]}|f''(x)|,$
$$|P_1(2R) - f(2R)| \leq \frac{c(2R-R)^2}{2!} \leq \frac{1}{R^2}R^2\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}.$$

This is bad since this means $f(2R) \geq \frac{1}{2}$. There are either some continuity assumptions that are missing, or you need to let your function decay over a greater distance.

Comment: thanks you're right. For me it would be okay if the second derivative in this interval is bounded by e.g. $\frac{C}{R^2}$. Then this should je enough, right?

Comment: Take e.g. on $(R,2R)$ $f(x)=\log\left((2R-x)\frac{e-1}{R}\right)$. Then $f(R)=\log(e)=1$ and $f(2R)=\log(1)=0$. Now, one has to smooth the function around $x=R$ and $x=2R$ so that it becomes twice differentiable. Moreover $|f'(x)|\leq \frac{e-1}{R}$ and $|f''(x)|\leq \frac{(e-1)^2}{R^2}$. To smooth this function and keep the estimates on the derivative shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Wouldn't f(R) = log(e-1)? You get a I think if you use $f(x) = \log\left(2R-x)e/R\right)$ as you did before, you get $f(R) = 1, f(2R) = 0.$ You can smooth the function and you get the estimates on the derivative, but the constants in this case would be $|f''(x)| \leq e^2/R^2.$

Comment: Also in regards to your first comment yes.